# Shorting LM317 in/outputs to skip over it and get full input voltage

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, lm317, short-circuit

I am new to the electronics world. I wanted to make a variable voltage source for various uses. I decided to use the LM317. I will be using a slide switch instead of the dip switch to select between 9V, 5V, 3.3V and variable voltage as shown in the diagram.

[image]

My question is: Is it safe to jump over the LM317 to get the full 9V? Will it cause any problems to the IC? I didn't have any problem using Multisim simulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be fully safe, I would disconnect the LM317 from the circuit by disconnecting the output when you bridge over the 9V.

That being said it probably won't hurt the LM317 to have 9V on the input and output, there isn't anywhere for current to go except through the ADJ pin, in that case it would be good to also disconnect the resistor to ground on the adj pin. (if you don't you could get a lot of current leaving the resistor divider, and ~120mW on the resistor) So it might be OK just to try it, as long as the resistor divider to ground is disconnected there won't be current going through the chip, just depends on if you are no risk or some risk.

It will also be important to sequence the switch, so care would be needed in sequencing the jumpers, with the adj pin removed first then 9V jumper connector across the LM317.

Comment: what if i added an on-on switch at the output of the curciut to switch between 9v and lm317 output ? this way the the lm317 output will be disconnected when the bridge is connected.
check this [diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRYF9.png)

Comment: That would be better, and the adj pin should also be disconnected so if you have the switch disconnect both the LM317 and R1 (both) then that would be better.

Comment: the simulation shows current spike at the vout pin from 8mA to 13mA when the bridge is connected and the output is disconnected which does not seem like a big problem. if i can trust the simulation XD
Anyway thanks for the help